# Branch points of $\sqrt{\cos(z)}$.

Tags: taylor-expansion, laurent-series, branch-cuts, branch-points

I’m asking this question because I’m trying to write the series expansion of $\sqrt{\cos(z)}$ about $0$, and it seems problematic because its series expansions are not unique (if I’m doing the calculations correctly).

I guess this problem is linked to branch points. Since $\sqrt{z}$ has branch point at $0$ and infinity, I think the branch points of $\sqrt{\cos(z)}$ should be $\cos(z) = 0$, therefore don’t include $0$. Then why does $\sqrt{\cos(z)}$ have a non-unique series expansion about $0$, the point at which it’s analytic?

Comment: $\cos(z)$ does have two analytic square roots on simply connected open subsets of $\Bbb{C}-(\pi \Bbb{Z}+\pi/2)$, more generally any open subsets of $\Bbb{C}$ such that any closed curve encloses an even number of elements of $\pi \Bbb{Z}+\pi/2$.

Comment: There truly are two analytic functions in a neighbourhood of $z=0$ whose square is $\cos z$: they are negatives of each other. Does that resolve the ambiguity in your calculations, or are other problems arising?